# How does the "magic lines(s)" in python work, when specifying encoding in python file?

Tags: python, encoding, comments, interpreter

At the start of a python file (first line) sometimes I read

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and sometimes I read

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Both lines seem to do the same thing: specifying utf8 as encoding for all the text put in the file.

I have to questions:

1. Why does this even work? I thought the interpreter ignores everything after a `#` because it invokes a comment.
2. What is the difference between the two lines above? Does the interpreter just *ignore* the `-*-`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two forms are equivalent.  The `-*-` version is a special kind of comment that Emacs understands.  See [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more information.

If a comment like in either of these forms is one of the *first two lines* of a file, the interpreter will use the specified encoding to read the file.

Answer (score 3):

It works because the implementation looks for it, there is nothing magical about it. There is no difference, all possible variants are defined by [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) (the only difference is that the first one is Emacs-compatible).